# Does waitpid alone enough to kill a process?

Tags: c, kill, waitpid, sigterm

Does this line of code kill and reap a child process without a kill operation?

```
waitpid(pid,&cs,0);
```

Or, must it be in this format to kill and reap a process?

```
kill(pid,SIGTERM);
waitpid(pid,&cs,0);
```

Comment: `waitpid` waits for a process that has voluntarily exited, or that has been terminated by a signal.  But no, `waitpid` doesn't do any killing itself.

Comment: @SteveSummit Then, if I waitpid a child in parent process without killing the child, should it wait forever?

Comment: Yes -- or until the child exits on its own.

Comment: If you don't want to wait forever, you can pass `WNOHANG` to `waitpid`: `waitpid(pid, &cs, WNOHANG)`. See [`waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Comment: The thing is for some reason(probably I just forgot) I didn't kill the child process but just waited it(with 'waitpid' without 'WNOHANG') in my code. Still it doesn't go to infinite loop and when I check processes with 'ps aux | grep Z', I see no zombies. Weird. @SteveSummit